# Attach events to elements in jQuery in an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am learning Backbone.js and jQuery in an effort to freshen my client skills.  I have hit a snag in the rendering of a view that I cannot attach evens to children elements,, while iterating  over them in an each function / loop.  Here is the relevant portion of the render function

```
var NavigationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#nav-navigation')
    , firstRender: true
    , template: _.template($('#tpl-nav-organization').html())

    , initialize: function(){

        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); 
        this.collection.on('add', this.render);     
    }

    , render: function(){


        var $that = $(this);
        var proxy = $.proxy(this.navigateTo, this, 'parameter to navigateTo')

          // log point 1   
          console.log(proxy)

        $.each(this.el.children, function(index, child) {

            var navId = $(child).attr('id')
            if(navId !== undefined) {
                var navSelector = '#' + navId

                var proxy = $.proxy(this.navigateTo, $that, 'parameter to navigateTo')

                          // log point 2
                  console.log(proxy)

                $(navSelector).on('click',proxy);
            }
        })              


    }
    , navigateTo: function(id) {
        console.log(id)
    }
}) ;
```

At "log point 1" I get a valid function logged:

```
function () {
            return fn.apply( context || this, args.concat( core_slice.call( arguments ) ) );
        }
```

At "log point 2" I get "undefined" logged.  I tried this

```
var $that = this
```

and passing this in the loop.  None of this is working (no pun intended).  I realize my design of my application needs to evolve, but I am trying to understand this problem in this context.  Why can  not create a valid proxy to my navigateTo method of the NavigationView class?

In addition to the answer to making the code work - I would love to know why.  I suspect that inside of the loop the this object is a different context.  But why can't I store that context prior and have it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because inside the $.each loop `this` points the value of the current index of the array, not to the object you assume it is pointing to

```
var self = this;
$.each(this.el.children, function(index, child) {

        var navId = $(child).attr('id')
        if(navId !== undefined) {
            var navSelector = '#' + navId

            var proxy = $.proxy(self .navigateTo, $that, 'parameter to navigateTo')

                      // log point 2
              console.log(proxy)

            $(navSelector).on('click',proxy);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, its great to be back on stack (long time user w/ myOpenId account).  What is the difference between "var $that = $(this);"  and "var self = this" I assume the former is the jQuery context?

Comment: @akaphenom `$(this)` is a jQuery wrapper for the dom element referred by `this`, so they are not the same again